# Changing line thickness without changing line length

Tags: plotting

Is there any way to change the thickness of line without changing the width?

For instance, the following example shows that as thickness increases, the white gap decreases. Is there any way to maintain the gap?

```
Show[
    ListPlot[{{0, 2}, {13.4, 2}}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True,
             Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[0.01]}],
    ListPlot[{{14.7, 2}, {24, 2}}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> None,
             PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[0.01]}]
]
```

[image: thin lines with gap]

```
Show[
    ListPlot[{{0, 2}, {13.4, 2}}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True,
             Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[0.05]}],
    ListPlot[{{14.7, 2}, {24, 2}}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> None,
             PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[0.05]}]
]
```

[image: thick lines without gap]

Comment: Could you please edit your post (edit link below it) and use the `{}` button on the toolbar to format it for readability?

Answer (score 20):

Use `CapForm["Butt"]` in `PlotStyle` to tell the system that the line must end exactly at the specified coordinates.

```
PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Gray, Thickness[0.05]]
```

Comment: Aha! This solved a problem of mine when I exported plots to pdf the thicker line went outside the frame slightly! Thanks! +1